# why is letter-spacing for @font-face not working?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, multilingual

I'm working on a multi-language site and have used @font-face to display the Burmese Font. All looks good except letter-spacing. Thus i tried to insert letter-spacing inside @font-face. But it has no effect. Using letter-spacing inside body or html or container pushes the letter-spacing for other fonts as well and that's not what i'm looking for. I just want to increase the letter-spacing for this  Zawgyi-One font as shown below.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Zawgyi-One';
    src: url('/fonts/Zawgyi-One.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/Zawgyi-One.eot?iefixa') format('eot'),
         url('/fonts/Zawgyi-One.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/Zawgyi-One.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/Zawgyi-One.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    unicode-range: U+00-FF, U+980-9FF;
    letter-spacing: 0.30em!important;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Looks from the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) that `letter-spacing` is not supported as part of the font-face definition.

That said, I would define the font face, then define a class to apply to objects with that font family declaration.

For example,

```
.zawgi-one {
  font-family: 'Zawgi-One';
  letter-spacing: 0.30em !important;
}
```

Comment: If you're using SASS, you can also take advantage of the `@extend` to achieve the effect :)

Comment: but i'll be using more than one font in the same and many more. All the pages are combination of many fonts. I mean same place might have arial, zwagi-one, Helvetica Neue fonts. All these contents are feed by the users from the front-end to the database and thus can't control it individually. Any suggestions ??

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  You can't have one character display in more than one font.  If you have regions of the page with this letter spacing, then apply it (though that seems like a bad idea b/c every font is different).

Comment: I just want to increase the letter-spacing for that Zawgyi-One font anywhere it is displayed in the page leaving the letter-spacing of other fonts untouched.

Comment: Well, you currently apply that font in some manner, right?  Whatever you're doing at the point the font is set, tweak to add the class instead.

Comment: @JeremyMiller He meant that he has several alternative fonts in a `font-family`, and only one of them needs `letter-spacing`. Consider using Segoe UI with an alternative of Open Sans: the second one needs -0.02em of spacing to be compatible.